# Create table with percentiles query

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a new table from a percentiles query so I can export it into ARCGIS. I am getting a syntax error, however, that I do not know how to address.

```
create table tempercent as (select *,  percentile_CONT(.95)  
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY cast(travel_time_minutes as float)) OVER (PARTITION BY TMC_code) AS TTAV_P_80 FROM [dbo].[Andy_I40])
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server does not support CTAs. You could use `SELECT ... INTO` instead:

```
SELECT *,  PERCENTILE_CONT(.95)  
      WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY cast(travel_time_minutes as float)) 
      OVER (PARTITION BY TMC_code) AS TTAV_P_80 
INTO tempercent
FROM [dbo].[Andy_I40]
```

Comment: @benfardot [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)